# possible orders of world series game

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The World Series in baseball continue until either the Team A or Team B wins four games. How many different orders are possible (e.g., ABBAAA means
the Team A wins in six games) if the series finishes at
(1) 5-th game?
(2) 6-th game?
(3) 7-th game?

---

**My Attempt:**

For all problems, just consider a case that team A win and multiply $2$ for team B.

Let A, B denote team A, B and O denotes empty slot.

(1) There are 5 slots : OOOOO

But, a last one must be A because, if not, the game doesn't continue until 5-th game.

So, possible slot is OOOOA. From game-rule, A must win 4 times and this implies there is one B.

Hence there are $4$ cases for team A win ($\binom{4}{1}$) and multiply $2$ for total cases.

---

(2) Similarly, there are 6 slots : OOOOOA (same attempt for a last slot).

A should win 4 times so there are 2 B : $\binom{5}{2} * 2$ is total cases.

---

(3) there are 7 slots : OOOOOOA

There are 3 B : $\binom{6}{3}$*2 is total cases.

---

Are these correct? If not, what should I modify to count all possible different orders?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations are correct.

As a check as to whether this looks reasonable, the number of ways of finishing in the 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th game would be $2,8,20,40$ possibilities respectively. Then taking the possibilities for games not played you would see $2\times 2^3 +8\times 2^2 +20\times 2^1 +40\times2^0= 128$ patterns for seven games played in full.  That should have been $2^7=128$ so your method produces credible results.